# В чем причина ошибки при написании процедуры MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

При написании процедуры средствами phpMyAdmin возникает следующая ошибка. Внутри процедуры планируется сделать транзакцию. Как только я добавляю транзакцию (даже самую простую, ради теста) - возникает ошибка.

Версия 10.4.16-MariaDB

```
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `bank_account_transaction` (`bank_account_id`) VALUES (bank_card_sender_id)
    COMMIT WORK;
END;
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Данный запрос не был выполнен: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `transfer_money`(IN `bank_card_sender_id` INT, IN `bank_card_reciever_id` INT, IN `amount` INT) DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN;
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `bank_account_transaction` (`bank_account_id`) VALUES (bank_card_sender_id)
    COMMIT WORK;
END;"

Ответ MySQL: #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около ';
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `bank_account_transaction` (`bank_acco...' на строке 1
```

Comment: Если процедура состоит более чем из одного оператора, необходим BEGIN-END.

Comment: Так тоже ошибка.

Comment: Покажите **полный** код, который приводит к ошибке, **в виде форматированного текста**. Сообщение об ошибке тоже дайте форматированным текстом. Укажите также точную версию MariaDB. PS. А фотографии можете убрать - от них толку почти что ноль.

Comment: Готово. Все добавил.

Comment: Я починил. Добавил работающий вариант.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить BEGIN и корректно проставить все делиметеры (в данном случае ;)

```
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO bank_account_transaction (transaction_id, bank_account_id) VALUES (2, bank_card_sender_id);
COMMIT WORK;
END
```

Comment: Это - полный текст процедуры? в таком случае и `START TRANSACTION;`, и `COMMIT WORK;` - лишние. Хотя бы потому, что единичный запрос - это ВСЕГДА транзакция. И потому, что дефолтно автокоммит включён. И ещё потому, что BEGIN сам по себе стартует транзакцию. А с учётом того, что во всей процедуре один-единственный оператор, BEGIN-END тоже не нужен. И вообще непонятно, зачем надо простейший INSERT заворачивать в процедуру.